How to get confidence values of estimated joints in pose estimation?
In pose estimation, there are confidence values to indicate the estimated joints are how much correct. But, those are computed if the input is image type.
In my case, I predicted a pose using my model, my input is only joint coordinates.
So, the output also only joints coordinates.
Therefore, I would like to calculate confidence values for the predicted joint coordinates.
In testing phase, some inputs have not ground truth joints.
Please guide me how can I calculate the confidence for the predicted joints.
I want to use those confidence values for next phase.
